# Set delay before ng-walkthrough directive fires

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently using the [ng-walkthrough](https://github.com/souly1/ng-walkthrough) directive (Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kHM9zHCxAA3gPYvedmdw?p=preview) to create a series of on-screen instructions for my application.

I would like to set a delay before the animation automatically loads. Does anyone know the best way of doing this?

[image]

**controller.js**

```
$scope.showAccountsWalkthrough = true;

$scope.accountsWalkthrough = {
    steps : [
        {
            id: "new-account-button",
            text : "Some text here"
        },
        {
            id: "scan-all-button",
            text : "Some text here"
        },
        {
            id: "accounts-list",
            text : "Some text here"
        }
    ],
    currentIndex : 0
};

$scope.nextAccountsWalkthrough = function() {
    ionic.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        if($scope.accountsWalkthrough.currentIndex < $scope.accountsWalkthrough.steps.length-1) {
            $scope.accountsWalkthrough.currentIndex++;
            $scope.showAccountsWalkthrough = true;
        }
    });
```

}

**view.html**

```
<walkthrough
    id="accounts_view_walkthrough"
    walkthrough-type="transparency"
    focus-element-id="{{ accountsWalkthrough.steps[accountsWalkthrough.currentIndex].id }}"
    main-caption="{{ accountsWalkthrough.steps[accountsWalkthrough.currentIndex].text }}"
    force-caption-location="BOTTOM"
    is-active="showAccountsWalkthrough"
    is-bind-click-event-to-body="true"
    on-walkthrough-hide="nextAccountsWalkthrough()"
    is-round="false">
</walkthrough>
```

Comment: what about taking `showAccountsWalkthrough` in `setTimeout` ?

Comment: @swapnesh - how would I do that? Can you show me a code sample please

Comment: What does this `is-bind-click-event-to-body="true"` option do? I did not see it in the documentation for the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved the issue.

```
    setTimeout(function(){ 
         $scope.showAccountsWalkthrough = true;
    }, 1000);
```